# Search-Mailbox command not recognized exchange 2010 sp1 powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, exchange-server-2010

Does anybody know why this command is not recognized in Exchange 2010 SP1:

```
Search-Mailbox -Identity "April Stewart" -SearchQuery 'Subject:"Your bank statement"' -DeleteContent
```

Comment: Are not the other Exchange commands recognized as well? Can you report the error?

Comment: The term 'Search-Mailbox' is not recognized as the name of a  cmdlet, function, script file or operable problem....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following to fix the problem:
http://www.techieshelp.com/delete-mail-from-multiple-mailboxes/

Answer (score 11):

This problem happens because your account is not a member of the `Discovery Management` role.  Since your account does not have permission to perform searches, `Powershell` does not import the `Search-Mailbox` cmdlet.

In `ECP`, add the account to this role, then close and restart your `Powershell` session.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this from the Exchange Management Shell? If you're running from a regular powershell instance, did you remember to import the module? Run `get-module` to find the name of the exchange module, then run `import-module <modulename>` to make the commands available.

Comment: I ran it from the Exchange Management Console Shell.

Answer (score 0):

Create "Mailbox Import-Export Management" role group and grant yourself as a member.
Rerun Search commands and it will work.

To create the role group we need to run the following:
New-RoleGroup "Mailbox Import-Export Management" -Roles "Mailbox Import Export"

Adding a user can be done by running the following:
Add-RoleGroupMember "Mailbox Import-Export Management" -Member

http://blogs.technet.com/b/nawar/archive/2010/06/24/permissions-to-import-or-export-mailbox-data-in-exchange-2010.aspx